How to obtain filtered averages from the same column in Excel using several conditions?
For context, I have an excel Data Frame (We will call it SurveyData) containing Quality scores provided to persons by two methods: AI and User Generated scores (See example below). These scores come irregularly, and User generated scores tend to be lower in quantity (Usually a 1:20 ratio comparing with AI generated scores). User genenerated scores show as Blanks in the survey method column, they can start a survey but not finish it (Showing Abandoned in the status column and not prroviding any score, and AI generated scores don't generate any status, just the score. There can be multiple surveys for a each person on the same week.
SurveyData Data frame



Person
Survey Method
Score
Status
Week ending
Access Key




A
AI
3

10/27/2024
ID


B


Abandoned
10/27/2024
ID


A
AI
4

10/27/2024
ID


A

2
Completed
10/27/2024
ID


B
AI
4

10/27/2024
ID


A

3
Completed
10/27/2024
ID


C
AI
4

10/27/2024
ID


C


Abandoned
10/27/2024
ID


A
AI
2

10/27/2024
ID


B

4
Completed
10/27/2024
ID



I have a Pivot table that comes from another data frame (Called PersonData) where I want to add the averaged survey score for each person each week, using the information from SurveyData.
Pivot table coming from AgentData Table



Week ending
Person
AI Score Avg
U. Gen Score Avg




10/27/2024
A





B





C





Since both Data Frames can be crossed using a field called Access Key, which is unique per week and per person, I tried using this formula to get the average user generated score for each person using all scores in that week. The idea was to only use the scores of rows that have user generated scores (Blanks in Survey Method) and show as completed, to avoid adding blank scores into the equation, using the following formula:
=IF(XLOOKUP(AgentData[@[Access Key]],SurveyData[AccessKey],SurveyData[Survey Method],"", 0,1) = "", AVERAGE(FILTER(SurveyData[Score],AND(SurveyData[AccessKey] = AgentData[@[Access Key]], SurveyData[Status] = "Completed"))),
"")

This formula shows an error in the FILTER function, because the AND condition is always false, even if the conditions are true. I checked and standarized the data to avoid any typing errors but the issue persisted. When using one conditional the formula works, but I want to separate both score types because they have different weights due to the ammount of surveys being independent for each type. Can someone help me understand if there is a way I can do this alternatively? Combined Pivot tables could be used, but I would really like to grasp the concept of why this formula might not be working when adding two conditions. Thanks in advance.

You didn't post the sample data for the AgentData table. AccessKey is misspelled either in the formula or the SurveyData sample data and all the values are ID. Please add the missing information to your post.

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish:
=IFERROR(
     AVERAGE(
          FILTER($C$2:$C$11,($A$2:$A$11=I4)*($D$2:$D$11="Completed"))),"N/A")

The generic formula for FILTER with multiple criteria is:
=FILTER(range,(criteria1)*(criteria2),"Error message")



Reason for #CALC! error in FILTER(SurveyData[Score],AND(SurveyData[:
FILTER's include needs to be

A Boolean array whose height or width is the same as the array

Since AND always returns a single value and does not match the number of rows in SurveyData it results in error.

As Michal explained, use multiplication for AND:
=AVERAGE(
    FILTER(
        SurveyData[Score],
        (SurveyData[AccessKey] = [@[Access Key]]) *
            (SurveyData[Status] = "Completed"),
        0
    )
)


